# org.json.JSONException:Value unsuccessful of type java.jang.String can not be converted into JSONObject

Tags: android

I'm getting this error while fetching the json data from online server. Code will run fine in local server. I'm confused why it will happens with online server link.
Please help me ...
[Can not get json String response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk6mF.png)

Comment: Please add your code as text to facilitate readability and help others to potentially reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Amit, if I'm understanding it correctly when you are trying to get a json response from a local server you are able to run your client code successfully, but when you are trying to connect to a server over the network / internet it fails.

Comment: Is your server PINGable from your machine?
Are you able to access the service via the browser on you local box or have you checked the connectivity to the service using telnet?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to access this via browser....see this http://amdit.ga/api_india.php

Comment: I'm not able to access this link, says the site can't be reached can you check the URL again?